# ubuntu 18.04 issues with digikam

Tags: apt, 18.04, dpkg, dependencies, digikam

I have just upgraded to 18.04 and am trying to install upgrades and or new programd via the terminal. I get the following message

```
digikam-private-libs : Depends: libkf5sane5 (>= 4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libqtav1 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libqtavwidgets1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
i have tried  sudo apt --fix broken install and get this message.dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libqtav1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqtav1:amd64 (1.12.0+ds-4build3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtav1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtAV.so.1', which is also in package libqtav:amd64 1.11.0~git170314-xenial~ppa1
Preparing to unpack .../libqtavwidgets1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqtavwidgets1:amd64 (1.12.0+ds-4build3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtavwidgets1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtAVWidgets.so.1', which is also in package libqtavwidgets:amd64 1.11.0~git170314-xenial~ppa1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libkf5sane5_17.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtav1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtavwidgets1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to `apt remove digikam` and `apt purge digikam` and recieved this message

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 digikam-private-libs : Depends: libkf5sane5 (>= 4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libqtav1 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libqtavwidgets1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried to install aptitude and get the same message. Digikam appears as not installed in the Software center and when I press install I get an error message.Everything seem to work fine other than that. 
         Thanks a bunch,,,,,Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are packaging errors between two (16.04 and 18.04) releases.

So we can force installation of these packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libkf5sane5_17.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtav1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtavwidgets1_1.12.0+ds-4build3_amd64.deb
```

And then resume package installation with

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

For sure upgrade all package dependencies and reinstall your packages with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libkf5sane5 libqtav1 libqtavwidgets1
```